How to check if FlatGeobuf layer has a spatial index?
The GDAL vector driver for FlatGeobuf format has the layer creation option SPATIAL_INDEX=[YES/NO]. How can we check - with ogrinfo or similar - whether a previously created layer has a spatial index?

I don't think it's possible with ogrinfo but you can use the GDAL python API to check using osgeo.ogr.Layer.TestCapability. The capability to test is OLCFastSpatialFilter.
E.g.
from osgeo import ogr

ds = ogr.Open("has_index.fgb")
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

print(lyr.TestCapability(ogr.OLCFastSpatialFilter))

ds = ogr.Open("no_index.fgb")
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

print(lyr.TestCapability(ogr.OLCFastSpatialFilter))

Output:
True
False


Perfect, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.
